# Query dynamic object type in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Having the below field definition in a template.

```
"details": {
  "dynamic": "true",
  "type": "object"
}
```

This field is dynamically set based on the JSON schema, an example is the below.

```
"details": {
            "responses": [
              {
                "questionKind": "multiple_choice",
                "text": "Request Subscription",
                "questionOrder": 1,
                "order": 1
              }
            ]
          }
```

Is it possible to query ElasticSearch dynamic object datatype? I have tried the below but with no success.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "details.responses.questionKind": "multiple_choice"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Full index template:

```
{
  "index_patterns": "sponsorshipsinfluencers*",
  "order": 3,
  "version": 3,
  "aliases": {
    "sponsorshipsinfluencers": {}
  },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "true",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "influencerId": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "campaignId": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "campaignSponsorshipSetId": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "campaignSponsorshipId": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "acceptedDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "declinedDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "completedDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "paidDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "campaignType": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "createdTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis",
        "index": false
      },
      "updatedTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis",
        "index": false
      },
      "createdDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "updatedDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "details": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "type": "object"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what elastic version are you using ?

Comment: @Shachaf.Gortler 7.1

Answer (score 0):

I would try with out the `details` section it might be the document type name :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "responses.questionKind": "multiple_choice"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Not sure how this will navigate to a search query where the parent field is the 'details'.

Comment: can you share your index mapping

Comment: Index template document added. @shachaf-gortler